# tvos suppress white focus effect

Tags: uitableview, tvos

I am using this code to set the colour of UITableViewCells on focus:

```
class EpisodesTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    override func didUpdateFocusInContext(context: UIFocusUpdateContext, withAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {

        super.didUpdateFocusInContext(context, withAnimationCoordinator: coordinator)

        if let previous = context.previouslyFocusedView as? EpisodesTableViewCell {
            previous.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        }
        if let next = context.nextFocusedView as? EpisodesTableViewCell {
            next.contentView.backgroundColor = globalDarkGrey
        }
    }
}
```

The colour changes as desired, but not without a brief (and rather irritating) flash of the usual white focus colour when moving from one table row to another.

By not calling `super` I avoid the flash, but lose the on-click animation.

Any ideas of how to get rid of that white altogether?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the background color inside `addCoordinatedAnimations`:

```
coordinator.addCoordinatedAnimations {
        if let previous = context.previouslyFocusedView as? EpisodesTableViewCell {
            previous.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        }
        if let next = context.nextFocusedView as? EpisodesTableViewCell {
            next.contentView.backgroundColor = globalDarkGrey
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've marked this as the correct answer, although a couple of necessary tweaks are added below.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above was close enough to get me there, but here it is in a usable form:

```
coordinator.addCoordinatedAnimations({
    if let previous = context.previouslyFocusedView as? EpisodesTableViewCell {
        previous.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    }
    if let next = context.nextFocusedView as? EpisodesTableViewCell {
        next.contentView.backgroundColor = globalDarkGrey
    }
    }, completion: nil)
```